# Google Charts - Put data by PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, database

I`m trying put to google charts data by PHP echo (from the database). But charts show only one row from DB. Where I do a mistake? How to make charts to get data from all rows?

```
 function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Orders');
    data.addRows([
      ['<?php echo $rowb[0];?>', <?php echo $rowb[1];?>],
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Orders',
                   'width':1000,
                   'height':250};
```

Comment: What do you see in '<?php echo $rowb[0];?>'?

Comment: <?php echo $rowb[0];?> is a date and <?php echo $rowb[1];?> is a number count of items.

Comment: I've never used google Charts but `data.addRows()` it can be a json results from the file you fetched with ajax

Comment: can you also show where does `$rowb[0];` coming from?

Comment: <?php $stidb = oci_parse($conn1, "SELECT * FROM TABLE");
           
$rb=oci_execute($stidb);

while ($rowb = oci_fetch_array($stidb, OCI_BOTH)) {

?>

Comment: @user9557556 everything is on the same page?

Comment: yes, everything is in one page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
   $data = [];
   for($i = 0; $i< count($rowb); $i+2) {
     array_push($data, [$rowb[$i], $rowb[§i+1]]);
   }
?>
data.addRows(<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>);
```

Comment: what about explaining what your code does and how it solves OP's question? _"Try this"_ is not useful at all for reference for any further viewer of this question

Comment: It's not going to work without <?php  ; ?> inside the JS.

Comment: Hm.. $rowb[0] and $rowb[1] is constant. I do not need increase this number.

Comment: What do you get in <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>